# Show shortened URL

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop, url-shortener

I bring a doubt. I have an interface in which I have two TextBox, one in which a long url is entered and the other in which the shortened url is shown after the button is pressed. This code in a C # Form, I would like to know how to display the short url in the TextBox.

```
private void btnAcortar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//button
        {
            string urlCor = txtUrlLarga.Text;
            Shortener(urlCor);
        }

        public static string Shortener(string url)//Shortener method
        {
            string tinyUrl = url;
            string api = "tiny url api=";
            try
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create(api + url);
                var res = request.GetResponse();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    tinyUrl = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp);
            }
            return tinyUrl;
        }
```

This works on console, now I try to put it in a form.

Comment: set text property: `txtUrlShort.Text = Shortener(urlCor);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try...?

```
private void btnAcortar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//button
{
   string urlCor = txtUrlLarga.Text;
   txtUrlShort.Text = Shortener(urlCor); //assuming your textbox is called txtUrlShort
}
```

Comment: It's in Spanish. I bet you the box is called `txtUrlCorta` or something like that... :-)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Shortener(urlCor)
```

returns a string which you are not preserving.  Assign the return value to the variable you want the short url to be in.

```
string shortUrl = Shortener(urlCor);
```